# problems to add a string on mysql query result with python

Tags: python, mysql, string, list, executemany

I want to add a string to the result of my query in mysql.

I tried this code:

```py
mensaje = input ("introduzca el sms que desea enviar: ")
cursorsql1 = conectar.cursor()
sql = "select msisdn, '(mensaje)'VALUES(%s) as mensaje from perfiles where tarifa not like '%Iot%' and transparent_properties not like '%Momo%' and state like '%active%' and msisdn like '56943404789' and created_at between subdate(current_date, 1) and current_date".format(mensaje, values)
cursorsql1.executemany(sql,mensaje)
columnas = cursorsql1.fetchall()
print(columnas)
```

the error is this

> mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Parameters for query must be list or tuple.

i want the results looks like this

```
| 56953404789 | some message  |
```

Any idea what is happening to cause my error?

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Try putting your parameter as a list: `cursorsql1.executemany(sql, [mensaje])`

Comment: mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Failed executing the operation; Could not process parameters :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**
Provided the injection safe method:

---

Use the sql CONCAT function:

```
sql = "SELECT CONCAT(msisdn, ?) AS mensaje FROM perfiles"
cursorsql1.execute(sql, (mensaje,))
```

Note that on sqlite there is no CONCAT function, instead use the || operator:

```
"SELECT msisdn || ? AS mensaje FROM perfiles"
```

Comment: thankkkkss this work in this way: "SELECT msisdn, '{}' as mensaje from....".format(mensaje)

Comment: For the record that's very dangerous if you're designing it for other people to use, it's prone to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Thank you for the warning but it is for my personal use :)